# VBA : transcode the special characters

Tags: excel, vba, transcoding

Do you know please the VBA function to transcode the special characters like this data into "DÉLÉGATION" ?

[image]

Comment: How did you recieve this data? Looks like it's not imported correctly.

Comment: @JvdV it's the data from my excel file

Comment: Usually the answer is that the imported data has not been saved as the correct UTF-8 csv data.

Comment: @JvdV thank you, it's impossible to correct this data ?

Comment: There's very little information in your question which could allow us to help you.  Where is the data coming from?  Where is that screenshot from?

Comment: If **EVERY**  � equates to a `É`, you can use `Replace`. Otherwise, you will have to go back to the Source, and either generate it properly (if it wasn't), or Import it properly (more likely to be the case).

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, thank you, but I don't know how to write � in code VBA.

Comment: It is Unicode FFFD. Read about Unicode or wide characters.